# Keep my Wamp Server Online Forever

Tags: java, mysql

I've been searching on how to add a barcode scanner to my Java Project using my phone by connecting my software and scan the code using zxing app. Does anybody know of any examples or know how to do this easily? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Seriously - no idea what you expect us to do given this input.

Comment: It will keep running if you don't turn off your computer or you don't face any power cut.. lolzz

Comment: You could confugure the wamp server to start when windows start. Go to start -> accesories -> system tools -> task sceduler and add the wamp server

Comment: then what about when using in my friend pc

Comment: hmm can i do it for free if so plz tell me the steps too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you want to your database keep alive every time.I see two option there.

**One Option**

You have to keep on the computer where your wamp server run. Just like regular server. never stop keep running. This solution is some kind of stupid but its works for your problem.

**Two Option**

This is the best option. Configure your database in the hosting service. There are lot of free servers available.

Ex https://www.000webhost.com one of the free hosting services. 
You can create free database instance using this service and map your db configuration details in your software.(host_url, username, password etc.)

you can keep on your db for ever.

Hard to understand what are you looking for but i think this will help you.